# Checking if multiple inputs are of number type

Tags: javascript

Say I'm creating a function to add some numbers together, and I want to verify they are all actually numbers.

I am doing this:

```
function addNumbers(x, y) {     
    if (typeof x == 'number' || typeof y == 'number') {
        // do something..
    }        
}
```

It seems unpractical if I had more than two numbers.
What would be a better way to check for multiple numbers?

Comment: Pass them into the function as an array to begin with, so that you can easily loop over it …?

Comment: did you tried adding like addNumbers(10,11) ?

Comment: Please also include the inputs, how and where you are storing their values, and how you are calling the `addNumbers` function with those values. We can help you a lot quicker that way.

Comment: I'll clarify, i want the addNumbers function to take in any amount of values (for the purpose of learning, not any real application), and if any of them is not a number it will throw an error. So for instance, addNumber(1, 2, 3, 'twenty')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its more readable form, use `Array.prototype.every`, `Number.isInteger` and `Array.prototype.reduce`.

I'm not sure what you want to do with errors, so we just logging them (and the result);

```js
// consider floating point
const isNumber = n => typeof n == 'number' && !isNaN(n)

const addNumbers = (...args) => {
  const isValid = args.every(isNumber);
  // const isValid = args.every(Number.isInteger);
  if (!isValid) {
    console.log('Error');
    return;
  }
  const sum = args.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr, 0);
  console.log(sum);
  return sum;
}

addNumbers(5, 6);
addNumbers(5, 6, NaN);
addNumbers(5, '6');
addNumbers('5', '6');
addNumbers('5', 6);
addNumbers(5.5, 6);
addNumbers(5.5, 6, 6.4, 65);
addNumbers(5.5, 6, {});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for floating point numbers `Number.isInteger(5.2) is false`.

Answer (score 3):

You can put them in an array and use a Boolean flag to check if all are numbers, using `Array.prototype.every` (and check for `NaN`s, because `typeof NaN === 'number'`):

```js
function addNumbers(...args) {
  var all_numbers = args.every(a => typeof a == 'number' && !isNaN(a));
  if (all_numbers) {
    var sum = 0;
    args.forEach(n => sum += n);
    console.log(sum);
  } else {
    console.log('something is not right!');
  }
}

addNumbers(5, 6);
addNumbers(5, 6.2);
addNumbers(5, 6, NaN);
addNumbers(5, 6, []);
addNumbers(5, 6, {});
addNumbers(5, '6');
addNumbers('5', 6);
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is solving the problem when there are more than two inputs.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Using `...args` solves this problem.

Comment: try using isNaN instead

Comment: also try using "every" instead

Comment: also its the best usecase for reduce

Comment: @DennisVash Totally forgot that `typeof NaN === 'number'`, thanks.

Comment: I meant using the function isNaN

Comment: You can also use `return args.reduce((sum,n) => sum + n, 0);`

Comment: Could you please clarify this part of the code: var all_numbers = !args.some(a => typeof a != 'number' || isNaN(a)); in particular the !args

Comment: @DennisVash `isNaN([]) is false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use get your inputs as an array using the `...` rest parameter syntax then use `Array.prototype.reduce` to sum them and while doing so you can convert the elements to numbers using the `+` operator and add them:

```js
function addNumbers(...nums) {     
    return nums.reduce((sum, num) => sum + +num)
}
console.log(addNumbers(1, 2, "3", 4));
```

Or if you want to skip the non-numbers (which will produce `NaN` if you use the first code snippet) just check the type before adding, if number you're good else replace that with a `0`:

```js
function addNumbers(...nums) {     
  return nums.reduce((sum, num) => sum + (!(typeof(num) === "number") ? 0 : +num));
}
console.log(addNumbers(1, 2, "3", 4, "non-number"));
```

Comment: What if he want to protect against accidental inclusion of text inputs? Your solution this way returns a `NaN`.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yes, I realized my mistake added a second version

Answer (score 0):

You can push all your numbers into and array and run a loop over that array and add them.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4]; #be it your array

function addNumbers(arr) {
let sum=0;
arr.map(item => {
if(typeof item === 'number') {
sum=sum+item;
}
else {
return item+' is not a number in given array';
}
return sum;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance not the issue here:

```
function testN(){
    if(!Array.from(arguments).every((d)=>typeof d === "number")){
        return;
    }
    console.log("pass");
    //do something;
}
```

replace "do something" with whatever you want to do.
Can use negated "some" method, that'll terminate earlier. Whichever fits you.